# Clickatell callback url to receive messages not working

Tags: php, clickatell

I have a clickatell account and i am trying to receive messages in php using it. I understand that I need to setup a callback url on it and i have added that. In the callback url, i have added the following code snippet

```
<?php

$req = print_r($_REQUEST, true);
$req = wordwrap($req, 70, "\r\n");

error_log($req, 3, "test.log");
mail("<my-email-address>", "sms test", $req);
```

When i call the url directly, it is working as it should and sending me the mail as well as logging to the error log file. However, when i receive a text message in clickatell, nothing happens (no mail/log).

Am i missing something here? Any pointers are appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional details which would help to resolve/understand the problem.

Thanks

Comment: So you are saying that there's nothing newly added in the error_log file as well as no email is being sent to you, when an sms is received? Then, probably the callback url might not have been called by the clickatell server! They seem to have a LIVE CHAT support section in their website. See if you could get some quick help from there too.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran - Yes this helped. I figured out the problem. Have added it as an answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the customer support of Clickatell, i figured out that there are two places to add callback urls inside your clickatell account. The first one is under the API which i was adding and it wasn't working. The second, and correct place for my case, was under the mobile number settings. To be completely clear, if you check under the SB Subscriptions link in your account, you would see a mobile number and a settings link next to it. That is where you need to add the callback url.

Thanks everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things needed:

a) When you send your SMS message, you must ask for callbacks. How that is done depends on what API you are using. With the HTTP API, you would add &callback=3 as an example...

b) On your API connection (when you login to the Clickatell website), you need to specify your callback URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i did try both ways, but there is another place to add callback which i wasn't aware of. Added it as the answer now.